# Algorithm for covering memory ranges?

Tags: algorithm, memory

I have a set of ranges such as {(2-8), (13-22), (380-7931), (40032-63278)}. For the sake of simplicity we may assume that they do not overlap (overlapping ranges have already been merged).

My goal is to "cover" these ranges using combinations of a given set of "lengths" such as {4, 64, 1024, 16384}. I am constrained to use at most N lengths, such as N=32. I do not care how many "lengths" I use as long as I'm below my maximum, but I want to minimize total "extra" area - numbers "covered" by lengths that is not in the initial set of ranges.

Example {(2-8)} covered by (2-66) (one length of 64 used) has 58 "extra" numbers. {(2-8)} covered by {(2-6), (6-10)} (two lengths of 4) has only 2 "extra" numbers and is preferable.

My real world application involves pre-programming a fixed MMU TLB to ensure that only certain ranges of memory addresses are accessible (TLB misses thus represent a forbidden access & can be dealt with accordingly). I'd like to cover the ranges as tightly as possible so violations are caught sooner rather than later, but I only have 32 slots to work with and 4 fixed page sizes. I can tune my code by hand to an adequate level of performance, but I'm curious if there's a more elegant/general purpose solution to the problem. It seems related to the knapsack problem but different enough it's been difficult to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be formulated as variation of [Shortest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem).

We need to cover a set of *ranges* of total length **M** with at most **N** *pages*. *Pages* may have **L** different lengths, they are not aligned (may be placed at any address). Difference between total "extra" area and total length of *pages* is equal to the constant **M**, which allows to minimize total length of *pages*.

Let's construct a graph, related to this problem. Each memory address in any *range* has corresponding vertex in the graph. Each vertex has **L** outgoing edges, corresponding to **L** *pages*, starting at given address. Length of each edge is equal to *page* length. Each edge comes to some vertex in the graph, depending on where corresponding *page* ends:

1. *Page* ends in some unoccupied position. Edge comes to the vertex, corresponding to starting address of the first *range* after this position.
2. *Page* ends inside some *range*. Edge comes to the vertex, corresponding to end address of the page.
3. *Page* ends in unoccupied position, with address, larger than address of any *range*. Edge comes to *destination* vertex. (Starting address of the very first *range* corresponds to *source* vertex, and we should find shortest path between these two vertices).

Since the resulting graph is a [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), shortest path may be found in linear time, by processing the vertices in a topological order (or, even simpler, in order of corresponding memory addresses).

For each vertex keep an array of **N** pairs {path-length, back-pointer}. While shortest path algorithm visits any vertex, index this array with the number of hops in the path, and if the path is shorter than stored path-length, replace {path-length, back-pointer}. When every vertex is processed, find shortest path in the array of pairs, belonging to *destination* vertex, then reconstruct path using back-pointers. This path describes optimal cover.

Worst case time complexity O(L*M*N) is determined by maximal number of edges (L*M) and number of elements in the array, belonging to each vertex (N). If *ranges* are sparse, most edges come to starting address of some *range*, most vertices, corresponding to internal addresses are unused, and time complexity is much less.

This algorithm requires O(M*N) space, but for sparse *ranges* this may be significantly decreased if we put all the graph vertices (or maybe all length/pointer pairs) into a hash map.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that the ranges you want to cover are very low valued intervals ( lets call them "ranges" ) and the gaps( call them "extras" ) are very costly intervals. Now we want to minimized the total cost with at most N intervals( call "covers" ) which cover all the "ranges" and may contain some "extras".
The below algorithm is greedy in nature.

First take all the intervals ones which you want to cover ("ranges") and also the "extras" in between them.

1) Cover them with a big interval from min to max of the "ranges".

2) Iterate and removes the most costly "extras" (i.e. largest spanning) in between then 
and also count the divison as creating an extra "cover", until the number of covers becomes N or you run out of the costly "extras".

Answer (score 0):

Bottom-up greedy approach which works when each length is a multiple of the last:

Start with a set of minimum-length intervals which cover all ranges minimally. Merge the longest runs iteratively until you go below the maximum range count.

In your case, on a TLB, you likely have alignment constraints which are going to make the problem a bit trickier.